# how to create hotkey to show window?

Tags: c#

I am working on window application using c#
. i want to show my application window when i press keys, but i dont knowq how to create hotkeys .. tell me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create an application that starts and then installs a so called keyboard hook. A good example is here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

after that the application could be minimized to taskbar or to system tray. The eventhandler of the keyboard hook then reactivates the application.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use hooks for this, better use [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx) and [UnregisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646327(VS.85).aspx) win32 functions:

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
    private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

    [Flags]
    private enum MOD : uint
    {
        MOD_ALT = 0x0001,
        MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002,
        MOD_SHIFT = 0x0004,
        MOD_WIN = 0x0008
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, MOD fsModifiers, uint vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    protected override WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}
```